# Convert files to UNIX format using Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, dos2unix

I have an application that is developed in a Windows environment. The application itself gets deployed to a Linux environment. Each time I deploy this application I have to convert executable files to UNIX format using dos2unix. I originally thought this was caused by the Windows CP1252 encoding, so I updated Maven to encode the files to UTF-8. This didn't solve my issue and I quickly found out that this has to do with carriage returns and line feeds by searching this site. Is there a way to have Maven convert all of the files to UNIX format during the build process? I am using Maven 2.2.1 and Java 5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the Maven [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin to call the [fixcrlf](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) ant task:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ant-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ant-test</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <fixcrlf ... />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I tried <fixcrlf srcdir="${basedir}" eol="unix"/>, which seems to be working. I am also using the maven assembly plugin and it is now having issues reading the jar files due to this conversion. Any ideas on how I can get this to build on a Windows machine?

Comment: You probably want to add an includes or excludes attribute so you're only changing *.txt or whatever resources you're trying to modify

Comment: Thanks, the includes/excludes worked. It modifies the files in my source directories though, which will be OK if need be, but is there any way to have the Maven assembly plug-in run this ant task as it is building so that I won't have to revert or check in my files?

Comment: What resources are you trying to modify?  See the documentation for the antrun plugin, you can use maven expressions to reference build paths and other related paths.

Comment: Example on actual usage: `<fixcrlf srcdir="${project.build.outputDirectory}" eol="unix" includes="**/*.sh" />` - I'd also bind it to process-resources phase, not to package phase.

Comment: I find it interesting that [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html#Ant_Expressions_to_Maven_Expressions_Mapping) says maven-resources-plugin should be able to replace antrun plugin for fixcrlf task, but haven't seen any indication it would be able to

Answer (score 48):

The assembly plugin has a [`lineEnding`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet) option which can be used to control the line-ending of the files for a given `fileSet`. This parameter is precisely there to do what you want. Ultimately, you could build zip archives with with CRLF lines and tar.gz archives with LF lines.

E.g.

```
...
<fileSet>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/build/QA</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>start.sh</include>
    </includes>
    <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
</fileSet>
...
```

Possible values at this time include:

- "keep" - Preserve all line endings
- "unix" - Use Unix-style line endings (i.e. "\n")
- "lf" - Use a single line-feed line endings (i.e. "\n")
- "dos" - Use DOS-/Windows-style line endings (i.e. "\r\n")
- "windows" - Use DOS-/Windows-style line endings (i.e. "\r\n")
- "crlf" - Use carriage-return, line-feed line endings (i.e. "\r\n")