# Passing arguments to Maven release build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to release a library using Maven and perform a site-deploy to sourceforge (I have create an interactive shell first). The release is done by a Jenkins job (using the Maven Release Plugin for Jenkins).

I tried:

```
-X -e -Dresume=false -Dusername=puce release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Dusername=puce"
```

and

```
-X -e -Dresume=false -Dusername=puce -Darguments=-Dusername=puce release:prepare release:perform
```

but both times the job hangs at site:deploy of the first module:

```
 [INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ myproject-parent ---
 [INFO] Parent project loaded from repository: myGroupId:myOtherproject-parent:pom:1.0
 [INFO] Parent project loaded from repository: myGroupId:myOtherproject-parent:pom:1.0
 Using private key: /opt/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
```

When I stop the job, the following gets printed at end:

```
Password for ${username}@shell.sourceforge.net: channel stopped
```

which probably means that ${username} wasn't resolved.

How can I resolve the ${username}?

**Edit:**

Note that the following runs fine:

```
site-deploy -Psonatype-oss-release -Dusername=puce
```

**Edit 2:**
As part of release:perform maven executes the following command:

```
/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn -s /tmp/release-settings7797889802430474959.xml deploy site-deploy --no-plugin-updates --batch-mode -Psonatype-oss-release -P nexus -f pom.xml
```

`-Dusername=puce` doesn't seem to get passed to this maven command...

Also note that help:effective-pom shows the following maven-release-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
    <arguments>-Psonatype-oss-release</arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So 'arguments' gets defined and its value seems to reach the embedded maven command instead of the value passed on the command line...

Comment: Have you tried setting your username in settings.xml? http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overriding

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
    <arguments>-Psonatype-oss-release</arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

with

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
            <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            <arguments>-Psonatype-oss-release -Dusername=${username}</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

in one of the parents did the trick.

It seems to be a bug that the value on the command line doesn't override the value in the POM.

Answer (score 19):

What I've successfully done in the past is as follows:

- Define a property in the POM file, e.g.:

  ```
  <properties>
      <release.arguments></release.arguments>
  </properties>
  ```
- Add the POM property to the plugin configuration in the POM file, e.g.;

  ```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <arguments>${release.arguments}</arguments>
         ...
  ```
- Pass the argument through the property on the command-line, e.g.:

  ```
  mvn release:prepare -Drelease.arguments="-N -Prelease"
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to define a default if not passed in from the command line?

Comment: Yes, under the first bullet of my answer you can enter a default, such as:
`<properties>
<release.arguments>your defaults go here</release.arguments>
</properties>`

Comment: Similar question I wrote here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088735/why-cant-my-tests-see-my-system-property-when-i-release-on-jenkins  Your solution works.

Comment: Do you know how to pass the name of the git tag which should be applied to the release?

Comment: I use the `buildnumber` plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was similar to `Sander Verhagen's`. I added only line only though.

How I run:

```
mvn --batch-mode release:prepare -Denvironment=production
```

My config:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <tag>${artifactId}-${version}-${environment}</tag>
                <arguments>-Denvironment=${environment}</arguments>
              <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The difference is that now my submodules use the variable `environment` and I don't need to define it twice (I.e. `-Darguments=-Denvironment=production -Denvironment=production`). I also gives me the flexibility of not adding the properties tag.