# Why can't my tests see my system property when I release on Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I wrote some unit test code that prints out the value of a System.property named "JENKINS_BUILD".  This property has a value when I run these command locally:

```
mvn --batch-mode test -DJENKINS_BUILD=true
mvn test -DargLine="-DJENKINS_BUILD=true"
etc.
```

But no matter what I do, I cannot get this property into my tests when they are run on Jenkins.  This is the command line option I'm using there:

```
mvn -DargLine="-DJENKINS_BUILD=true" --batch-mode -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform
```

Slightly different, but I don't see why it would matter.  Why is `System.getProperty("JENKINS_BUILD")` null on Jenkins but "true" in my local environment?  Does this have something to do with using `release:prepare release:perform`?

[I think this is basically the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005437/passing-arguments-to-maven-release-build), but I'm not sure.  The difference is he's trying to pass arguments into the release plugin, I'm trying to pass them into the surefire plugin.  Also, I want to define the value in the command line without having to change my pom.xml.  Is there a way to do that?

**FWIW**, the solution that I linked to *does* work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you do not fork your JVM, the properties you set on the maven command line are found; but, if you do fork your JVM the properties need to be copied on the forked JVM's argment list.

I am guessing that you are forking some aspect of your build, but not passing in a new argline, or are passing in a new argline that doesn't copy the necessary value from the launched (set) property.

This might mean that you could need to set a default (empty) property to make your argline configuration correct in both cases where the argument is set and where the argument is not set.  That's what the second "example" in your link (Sander Verhagen's example) is detailing, even if it isn't explicit as to why.

As far as why this is often encountered in the maven-release-plugin, keep in mind that during the maven-release-plugin you have one "parent" maven process driving two complete nested maven builds.  Failure to pass arguments to the children builds will mean the children run without the required arguments (as they are only argument to the parent activity, not the two maven runs to build the release version and the next snapshot version.

Comment: Seems to me that the release plugin should use the test lifecycle instead of hacking together its own solution to run it.  That seems like it would solve the problem to me.  Am I wrong about that?  e.g., `mvn package` will run `test` along the way, but the release plugin is doing something special.

Comment: It is actually not a hacked-together solution.  It is just a less-used ability to run maven builds as slaves to maven builds.  Think about it, you don't really want to run just to test to release, because then you don't distribute (or package) the artifacts.  You can't run in the mainline build to distribute, as then you'd already have spent your walk down the lifecycle on the release version, and have nothing left to verify the next snapshot works (which you do want to do before committing it).  It's probably not ideal, but it's better than most alternatives.

Comment: The maven-release-plugin takes arguments configurations.  I'd give that a try, passing in the top-level args to the lower release builds.  P.S. The slave stuff is also what allows maven site to "compile and run the tests" even if you called "clean site", although that's done as an extension to the maven-surefire-report configuration.