# How to package shell script files on Windows using Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

we are writing shell scripts in the IDE of Window, and package the project including the shell scripts with assemply maven plugin.

When it is unpacked on Linux OS, there is no problem for the shell scripts is itself, but it has to be changed the format from windows to Linux.

I would ask if there are Maven plugin that supports to make the format transformation during maven packaging process

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of format changes? Line Endings ?

Comment: Yes,thanks @khmarbaise. I found an answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162275/convert-files-to-unix-format-using-maven

Comment: No this is not the right answer. Better use the assembly descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an Ant Task for that, cause maven-assembly-plugin's [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) is capable of doing so. See for `lineEndings`...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise for the explanation. Actually, there is an answer that is using assembly plugin and lineEndings in the reference url. I am exactly using this way